# Can we use Twitter Bootstrap to make any web design responsive? Any other alternatives?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Since Twitter BootStrap is a Responsive **Framework**, I am wondering if it can be plugged into any site.
In other words, if I don't have control over the team which is designing the web-pages then can I take their design (where elements like container, header, navigation etc can be of any dimensions) and make it responsive using BootStrap.
Or does BootStrap expects the web-design to be in certain dimensions in order to work properly.

Are there any other popular CSS Responsive libraries that can be easily plugged in?

**Edit**: based on Paul's comments, I realised my question is not too clear. So here we go:

I am essentially looking for a Responsive CSS library which is flexible (or tweakable) on the width/padding/margins of different elements. Most of the responsive libraries out their requires that website needs to be of say 1440px or 960px wide and then they give 'N'px of padding/margins to different containers. At the end, I know that no matter which library I choose, its CSS needs to be modified for my design. So is BootStrap easily tweakable or should I go for some other library?

Thanks,
Jags

Comment: "Responsive" means "displays differently in different conditions to offer a better experience". You can't automate that.

Comment: @paul: I know I will need to adjust my css for different conditions (device dimensions). The problem is that I have been given a website design (for PC) and I am told that I need to make it work in tablets and mobile. I know I will need to modify the arrangements of elements based on device. I want to know how suitable BootStrap is in this case. If not BootStrap then some other boilerplate on which I can build upon.

Comment: yup, I understand. I'm just not clear what you expect a framework like Bootstrap to do for you. It doesn't know what the HTML elements that this site uses should look like on different devices. Frameworks such as Bootstrap are like tools you can use to implement designs. You could use Bootstrap to re-do some of the work that this team have done, thus making it responsive. I don't know if that counts as "easily plugged in" though.

Comment: I think I am essentially looking for a responsive css library which is flexible (or tweakable) on the width/padding/margins of elements. Most of the responsive libraries out their demand that website needs to be of say 1440px wide and then they give 'N'px of padding/margins. At the end I may know its all css and needs to be adjusted for my design but how easy it to to tweak it is the question which someone who's experienced can answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I understand what you're getting at better now.

Comment: ok, take a look at my edit! Hope it can help now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure the same classes used from Bootstrap can help you in responsive but it use also class like `row` and `span12`, `span9`, etc...

So I think that is quite complex to use a framework on an existing website.

The best way is to create it manually, from Bootstrap you can just copy the `media queries` and having a look around on how it make all the elements responsive.

There are also many other framework that do that, Bootstrap is not the only one, using Google you can find many of these framework but Bootstrap is the best.

Few other frameworks:

- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- http://www.getskeleton.com/
- http://cssgrid.net/

A good blog post: http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/

---

Edit:

With Bootstrap you can customize many things before downloading the framework.

Simply go here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

As you can see you can change colors, font, etc... and number of columns, paddings, gutters, margins, etc... so maybe it fit very well what you're looking for. Hope it help.

Comment: yes, I came across that page as well Andrea. But did you noticed that its missing the main container width.

Comment: you can change that value from the css... there are just 5 media queries. I do it many times.

Comment: hmmm...worth trying then I guess. Thanks for the help Andrea